# How to change programmatically image which is shown in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to change programmatically image which is shown in Corona ?
I have loaded image and show on screen

```
local lana = display.newImageRect( "images/lana_zero.png", 70, 100 )
    lana.anchorX = 0
    lana.anchorY = 1
    lana.x, lana.y = 0, 100
```

How to on press on button to change content of lana and set image lana_one.png ?
I looked at DisplayObject but there is no function to change source.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create both images matching their positions:

```
local lana = display.newImageRect( "images/lana_zero.png", 70, 100 )
    lana.anchorX = 0
    lana.anchorY = 1
    lana.x, lana.y = 0, 100


local lana1 = display.newImageRect( "images/lana_one.png", 70, 100 )
    lana1.anchorX = 0
    lana1.anchorY = 1
    lana1.x, lana1.y = 0, 100
    lana1.alpha = 0
```

and then, on click switch the alpha to 1

```
local touchHandler = function(event)
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        if whichLanaIsVisible == 0 then
           lana.alpha = 0
           lana1.alpha = 1
           whichLanaIsVisible = 1
        else
           lana.alpha = 1
           lana1.alpha = 0
           whichLanaIsVisible = 0
        end    
    end
end

button:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

Warning!
You can't do `if lana.alpha == 0`, because alpha, even if set to 0 may not always be equal 0. It is almost 0 then. It may be 0.00002501 for example which is not equal to 0.

Comment: You should use the `isVisible` flag, instead of changing alpha to 0.

Comment: It's true, but you may do transition.to and perform a fadeOut if you use alpha instead of isVisible

Comment: in that case, you could use `transition.dissolve()` http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/dissolve.html

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.  This tutorial from Corona Labs shows 4 different techniques (including the one above):

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/11/26/tutorial-techniques-for-swapping-images/

The 4th option, using sprites is probably the best way.
Rob